# How to make my wishes come true

Tags: salat, dua

Assalamualaikum to all the brothers and sisters. Today I would like to know some of the important prayers to pray or things to do in order to get what I really want from the core of my heart. please help me out. I really want The Almighty Allah to listen to my prayers and I am willing to go to any extent for that.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As [Qur'an 53:39](http://quran.com/53/39) states:

> And that there is not for man except that [good] for which he strives

So you should strive for your wishes. As far as I know, there is not a prayer that instantly grants you your wishes.